# jQuery- Dialog remove for window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I am working on a responsive website. I have to create a popup for window size lesser than `480px`, but for desktop size, the content has to be visible (not inside the popup). I am trying not to repeat the content twice.

Here's [a fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanmani/rjevta0o/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize();
    $("#filterOpen").click(function() {
        $("#mobileFilter").dialog("open");

    });
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 480) {
        $("#mobileFilter").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            dialogClass: "test",
            modal: false,
            responsive: true
        });
    } else if ($(window).width() > 481) {
        $("#mobileFilter").dialog().remove();
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To begin with, you state `smaller than 480px`, but your code reads `if ($(window).width() > 480) {`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Following is the code.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $(window).resize();
                $( "#filterOpen" ).click(function() { 
                $( "#mobileFilter" ).dialog( "open" );

    });
            });

$(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 480) {
                $( ".ui-dialog" ).dialog().remove();

        }else if ($(window).width() < 480) {
             $("#mobileFilter").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                dialogClass: "test",
                modal: false,
                responsive: true
            });

        }
  });
```